# Is a global assignment in an async TS/JS function safe to not accidentally override existing values?

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await

I have a list of queries that are executed in parallel, and the results need to be assigned to a 2D HashMap.

Because it is a 2D HashMap, the keys might not exist, and may need to be created first, but is the code below safe in all cases? Or could there be situations where the assignment might override results from another query, that finished just a tiny bit before?

```js
results: Record<string, Record<string, string>> = {};

async searchAll(queries: string[]) {
  await Promise.all(queries.map(async (query) => {
    // network action
    const result = await search(query);
    
    // create the key if it doesn't exist yet
    // result.otherKey does not contain duplicates
    (this.results[result.key] ?? (this.results[result.key] = {}))[result.otherKey] = result.value;
  }));
}
```

And I guess a second question depending on the answer to the first, how would I go about synchronizing the second part without awaiting all queries first?

*Edit:
Thanks to the comments, apparently JS is executed sequentially no matter what, so anything until the next `return`/`await` will be executed alone which would make the code safe, aka there could not be a case where two `async` functions voth have the same `key` value, and both create a new map at the same time so that one of the results gets left out.*

Comment: It isn't safe at all, while you are conditionally creating the key you are unconditionally assigning so if the `result.key` and `result.otherKey` are the same for multiple results it's LWW. It's also going to be borderline impossible to figure out when it's "safe" to *read* from your global var as well, which is why no one uses global vars for async ops. Use something like `Promise.all` or `Promise.allSettled` to coordinate the logic.

Comment: Question is whether there might be duplicate  ´otherKey´ values, and if so, what is then the desired behaviour? First come, first serve?

Comment: Right, I didn't properly specify that, in my case, there would be no duplicate `otherKey` values

Comment: It is important to note that if 1) check if the key exists, then 2) immediately assign it if it doesn't exist, then you won't have an issue. Even within an async context, synchronous code will always be synchronous. In other words, after you `await search(query)`, everything until the end of that function will behave as you expect. It is not possible for 1) you to check if a key exists, 2) another async function in the loop to assign an object to that key, then 3) for the original function to set the default result key to `{}`. The other comments above still apply, though.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I guess that answeres my question, if JS only suspends the function at the `await` keyword, but otherwise always guarantees a function is executed until the end (or next `await`) before any other code gets executed, the code should work just as I expected!

Answer (score 0):

return the await Promise.all and return the result. Reduce it to format as you wich.

`result = (await searchAll(query)).reduce((o, r) => (o[r.key] = {...o[r.key], [r.otherKey]: r.value}, o), {})`

Something like that should works. I didnt tried the code, and i forgot the types so it needs probably a fix. But it s looking safer to it like this to me.
That way, all the queries will be done then the matrix will be made from the result of all the promises.